# How can I only read a specified line in a text file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently making an android app that needs to read quotes in a text file. I have code to read everything from my file and display it through a toast, but I do not know how I can just read a specific line from it (eg. only displaying line 5 in a toast).

Here is my code:

```kotlin
var string: String? = ""
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        val `is`: InputStream = this.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.quotes)
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(`is`))
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (reader.readLine().also { string = it } == null) break
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            stringBuilder.append(string).append("\n")

            Log.d("strings", stringBuilder.toString())
        }
        `is`.close()
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, stringBuilder.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useLines`, which lets you work with a Sequence of the lines from within the lambda and automatically closes the stream afterwards:

```
val fifthLine = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.quotes)
    .bufferedReader().useLines { it.elementAtOrNull(4) ?: "" }
```